# [[self.effectsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel text] returning nil on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The didSelecctRowAtIndexPath method is as follows:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.currSelectedRowTitle = [[self.effectsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel text];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushedByTableView" sender:self];
}
```

and the cellForRowAtIndexPath is as follows:

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.effectsArray)
    {
        [self loadEffectsInArray];
    }

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"EffectsCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    //6
    Effect *effectCellEffect = [self.effectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *effectCellText = effectCellEffect.name;
    //7
    [cell.textLabel setText:effectCellText];
    //[cell.detailTextLabel setText:@"5 stars!"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];
    //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    //cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = self.effectsTableView.tintColor;

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that [[self.effectsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel text] is returning nil on didSelectRowAtIndexPath. What is the problem?

Comment: @SushilKumar you shouldn't ever be using views as a way of storing data. The OP already has an array of all strings that he is using in `cellForRow` so he should be doing the same in `didSelect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the cells this way. Data should only ever be put in to a cell so it can display it. You should never use views to store data and then retrieve it later.

In your code you are doing...

```
Effect *effectCellEffect = [self.effectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *effectCellText = effectCellEffect.name;

cell.textLabel.text = effectCellText;
```

So in `didSelectRow` just do the same...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Effect *effectCellEffect = [self.effectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.currSelectedRowTitle = effectCellEffect.name;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushedByTableView" sender:self];
}
```

You could then possibly extract it into a function by refactoring as you are doing the same thing in two places but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: woah... nice... why didn't I think of that!

Comment: No worries, sometimes if you've been working too long on your project you begin to lose sight of the easier things :D

Comment: So this this obviously works but, seriously, what is wrong with trying to get the selected cell's title?... I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm... not sure why it doesn't work in this specific case. However, when you are running this it isn't just returning the already created cell. It is dequeueing an additional cell that contains the same data. This is taking up additional memory where it isn't needed. E.g. if you have 10 rows on screen then you will only ever need 10 cells to be queued. This will create 11. Also, generally it's bad practise to use views as data stores. In the pattern MVC you are using the V part to do M stuff. M = array of effects. C = controller. V = cell. You shouldn't mix them.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableviewCell *cell=(UITableviewCell *)[self.effectsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.currSelectedRowTitle = [cell.textLabel text];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushedByTableView" sender:self];
}
```

This might work...

Comment: It might work but you should never use views to store data like this. The OP already has an array of all the strings. He should be using that to get the string not the label in the cell.